# C# XML Serialization, Ignore Certain Nodes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Currently using the System.Xml.Serialization serializer. Deserializing a string that contains HTML markup will cause the serializer to remove the markup. What is the best solution to avoid this?

Here's what the XML looks like,

```
<String name="Computer3" lang="US_EN">
    HELLO <i>FRUITS</i>. I HAVE RELEASED A NEW VIDEO.
</String>
```

The `<i>` tags are getting removed upon deserialization, so the output message would look something like,

```
HELLO . I HAVE RELEASED A NEW VIDEO.
```

Comment: You should probably have your message wrapped in a `CDATA` tag so it gets treated as text-only, especially as it contains valid XML markup (your `<i>` tag). Alternatively, encode your value so the angle brackets are escaped (`&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to encode the string value to preserve any HTML markup in XML.

```
var encodeString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("HELLO <i>FRUITS</i>. I HAVE RELEASED A NEW VIDEO.");
```

Then you'll have to decode it whenever you're retrieving the value.

```
var normalString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("HELLO &lt;i&gt;FRUITS&lt;/i&gt;. I HAVE RELEASED A NEW VIDEO.");
```

Source  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h(v=vs.110).aspx